# Why does git do not provide a default when reverting a merge commit that is pushed to the remote branch?

Tags: git, git-revert

As I know in most situations, we do `git revert -m 1 <merge-hash>`.
Why don't they default to the first parent on reverting a merge commit?
Any reasons behind?

Also, in what cases will we have to use `-m 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git revert normally operates on commits with only a single parent. By not providing a default parent, git ensures that you're aware you're reverting a commit with 2 parents and have thought about what this means. (I'm just guessing as to why they don't default to `-m 1`.)

You need to use `-m 2` if you want to revert the changes made to the other branch. For example, assume you merge branch `feature` into branch `master`. Then, if you wanted to revert that merge commit, you'd normally revert the `feature` branch "out" of the master branch with `-m 1`. (The end result of the revert is the previous commit on the master branch.) If, instead, you did `-m 2`, you'd be "reverting master out of the feature branch". This rarely makes sense (because the end state would be the same as the current `HEAD` of your `feature` branch, but with some extra commits that apply some changes and then undo them). (The end result of the revert would be the previous commit on the *feature* branch.)